# Possible null reference after null check

Tags: c#, wpf, null, warnings

I have a problem resolving this CS8603 warning. Even though there is a null-check for `resource` variable, null reference is still possible. How come?

[image]

Code:

```
public string GetResource(string resourcePath)
{
    var resource = Application.Current.Resources[resourcePath];
    if (resource == null)
    {
        return $"{ResourceError} [{resourcePath}]";
    }

    // ToDo: CS8603
    return resource.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did correctly check wether `resource` is null. But even if it is not, `ToString()` might return null. You can use something like

```
return resource.ToString() ?? "";
```